# paypal billing agreement id is not coming

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am working with the paypal recurring payment using express checkout for variable amount.

I have almost done everything. I was following this guide:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/how-authorize-and-run-reference-transaction-express-checkout

After third step I am geting this response:

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2012-05-02T20:33:39Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 6361035da7d80
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 86
[BUILD] => 2840849
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 11455
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Buyer did not accept billing agreement
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Buyer did not accept billing agreement
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

Even step 4 is returning success for me but I am not receiving the BILLINGAGREEMENTID here.
I dont know what is wrong here. Please help me with this.

step 4 response is:

```
 Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-61326512J28943643
    [SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-04-23T20:15:29Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 9604631d916a1
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 86
    [BUILD] => 2808426
    [INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED] => false
    [SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT] => false
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 4N241225R9256962J
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME] => 2012-04-23T20:15:27Z
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT] => 11.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT] => 0.62
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON] => paymentreview
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE] => None
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Ineligible
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => None
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID] => EUS59DJENWC3E
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK] => Success
)
```

I have been working on this from at least 4-5 days.

Response after not using step 3:

```
 [TOKEN] => EC-6MD78480W9369745J
    [SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-05-02T20:38:13Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 72306d7db8c1b
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 86
    [BUILD] => 2840849
    [INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED] => false
    [SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT] => false
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 6EG31415FF2050208
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME] => 2012-05-02T20:38:11Z
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT] => 11.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT] => 0.62
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON] => paymentreview
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE] => None
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Ineligible
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => None
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID] => EUS59DJENWC3E
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK] => Success
```

Comment: Rahul are you getting BILLINGAGREEMENTID in step 3?

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque No I am not receiving BILLINGAGREEMENTID in step 3

Comment: Rahul if you look out in step 3 you should get BILLINGAGREEMENTID as a response. Kindly check

Comment: @rahul You won't get a BILLINGAGREEMENTID in step 4 unless you pass it in your request (as REFERENCEID). Please show us the results of step 3, then we can help you further.

Comment: I am not getting how to solve this "Buyer did not accept billing agreement".

Comment: @rahul can you please let me know how did you resolved this? It is getting as "Merchant not enabled for reference transactions" in Step1 and "Buyer did not accept billing agreement" in Step 3 for me.  Can you please suggest me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sandbox then the reference transactions are needed to be turned on for the sandbox account. A billing agreement with paypal i think is a reference transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In step 3, You don't need to call method **CreateBillingAgreement** if you are already specifying **billingtype = MerchantInitiatedBilling** in step 1.

Please try this and update with the response.

Hope this helps.